# Error during static build of libvorbis and libmp3lame

Tags: gcc, ffmpeg, math, static-linking

I'm having trouble trying to build a static binary of ffmpeg - I've got almost the whole build working, with the exception of two libs - libvorbis and libmp3lame.

These two libs are failing during ./configure, specifically on undefined functions from the `math.h` / `libm`:

```
libvorbis:

gcc -L/vol/build/lib -static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,noexecstack -I/vol/build/include -L/vol/build/lib -o /tmp/ffconf.UKKLGhCv/test /tmp/ffconf.UKKLGhCv/test.o -lvorbis -lm -logg -lstdc++ -lpthread -lexpat -ldl -lm --enable-libopencore-amrnb
/vol/build/lib/libvorbis.a(envelope.o): In function `_ve_envelope_init':
envelope.c:(.text+0x983): undefined reference to `_ZGVbN2v_sin'
envelope.c:(.text+0x9a9): undefined reference to `_ZGVbN2v_sin'
/vol/build/lib/libvorbis.a(lsp.o): In function `vorbis_lsp_to_curve':
lsp.c:(.text+0x650): undefined reference to `_ZGVbN2v_cos'
lsp.c:(.text+0x669): undefined reference to `_ZGVbN2v_cos'


libmp3lame:

gcc -L/vol/build/lib -static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,noexecstack -o /tmp/ffconf.dC4w1f5B/test /tmp/ffconf.dC4w1f5B/test.o -lmp3lame -lm -lstdc++ -lpthread -lexpat -ldl -lm --enable-libopencore-amrnb
/vol/build/lib/libmp3lame.a(psymodel.o): In function `init_s3_values':
psymodel.c:(.text+0x14d3): undefined reference to `_ZGVbN2v___exp_finite'
psymodel.c:(.text+0x14fa): undefined reference to `_ZGVbN2v___exp_finite'
/vol/build/lib/libmp3lame.a(psymodel.o): In function `psymodel_init':
psymodel.c:(.text+0xb62d): undefined reference to `_ZGVbN4vv___powf_finite'
psymodel.c:(.text+0xb677): undefined reference to `_ZGVbN4vv___powf_finite'
psymodel.c:(.text+0xb6c4): undefined reference to `_ZGVbN4vv___powf_finite'
psymodel.c:(.text+0xb711): undefined reference to `_ZGVbN4vv___powf_finite'
psymodel.c:(.text+0xb75b): undefined reference to `_ZGVbN4vv___powf_finite'
/vol/build/lib/libmp3lame.a(psymodel.o):psymodel.c:(.text+0xb7a2): more undefined references to `_ZGVbN4vv___powf_finite' follow
/vol/build/lib/libmp3lame.a(util.o): In function `fill_buffer':
util.c:(.text+0x28a6): undefined reference to `_ZGVbN2v_cos'
util.c:(.text+0x28cc): undefined reference to `_ZGVbN2v_cos'
util.c:(.text+0x28fb): undefined reference to `_ZGVbN2v_cos'
util.c:(.text+0x2921): undefined reference to `_ZGVbN2v_cos'
util.c:(.text+0x29cc): undefined reference to `_ZGVbN2v_sin'
util.c:(.text+0x29e8): undefined reference to `_ZGVbN2v_sin'
```

I can't figure out how to get these to sucessfully build. From what I understand, passing the `-lm` option should be enough, but apparently isn't. I checked for the presence of `libm.a`, which is located at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a`, I also tried to pass this directory in the `-L` flags, but no difference. The libs build fine when removing the `-static` flag, but the resulting binary is (duh) linked against libm.so.

Just in case, these are the flags I'm using to build the two libraries:

```
libvorbis:
./configure --prefix=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --disable-shared --disable-oggtest

libmp3lame:
./configure --prefix=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --disable-shared
```

I'd appreciate any pointers on how to fix or debug this any further.

Edit: after playing around with it some more, it seems like the `libm` is getting linked in - when I remove the `-lm` flag, I'm getting a ton more undefined references - `sin`, `cos`, `__pow_finite`, etc. When I put it back in, most of these go away and only those mangled symbols, such as `_ZGVbN4vv___powf_finite` and `_ZGVbN2v_cos` remain.

Comment: These symbols may be indeed missing from libm. You could verify with: `readelf -s [path-to-libm] | grep [symname]`

Comment: I may be off but it seems these symbols are not in `libm` - they don't demangle well. They may be part of the library itself. Check this link: `https://dev.solus-project.com/file/data/7dedblvkcdk5kmw3ltvn/PHID-FILE-27qhoqo6wsubrntfj2xc/D1210.diff`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I managed to solve it - googling the mangled symbols such as `_ZGVbN2v_cos` led me to [this patch](http://sourceware-org.1504.n7.nabble.com/PATCH-1-14-x86-64-Vector-math-functions-vector-cos-td316235.html) mentioning vector math, and in combination with `ldd`'s output during dynamic linking mentioning `libmvec`, I realized that I might have to link that in as well.

For libmp3lame, it has to be linked in before libm:

```
gcc -L/vol/build/lib -static -o /tmp/ffconf.dC4w1f5B/test /tmp/ffconf.dC4w1f5B/test.o -lmp3lame -lmvec -lm
```

For libvorbis, the order of `-lm` and `-lmvec` doesn't matter, it builds either way.